# How to preserve state when performing operations on Java 8 Stream?

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

I need to parse a string consisting of different integers representing periods when a certain user was or wasn't watching tv.

I start by splitting the string and collecting it into an ArrayList:

```
final List<String> separated = stream(split(s, "A"))
  .map(str -> "A" + str)
  .flatMap(str -> stream(split(str, "B")).map(s2 -> s2.startsWith("A") ? s2 : "B" + s2))
  collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The tricky thing comes now. I need to transform those strings into domain objects with `from/to` fields.

So, in order to map this properly, my mapping function needs to be aware of the former element. So I did the following:

```
LocalDateTime temp = initial;

final ArrayList<WatchingPeriod> result = new ArrayList<>();

for (final String s1 : separated) {
    final WatchingPeriod period = new WatchingPeriod(temp, temp.plusMinutes(parseLong(substring(s1, 1))),
                    s1.startsWith("A"));
                    result.add(period);
        temp = period.getTo();
    }
    return result;
```

I feel it's a huge step back since I am breaking the whole stream pipeline just in order to get back to the old school for-each.

Is there any way I can do the whole processing in one stream pipeline? I am thinking about creating a custom Collector that would look at the last element in a collection and calculate correct LocalDateTime objects basing on this.

Examples:

input string: "A60B80A60", which means that someone was watching something for 60 minutes, then stopped for 80 and then watched again for 60 minutes

and as a result I'd like to get a List with objects:

1) from: 0:00, to: 1:00, watched: true

2) from: 1:00, to: 2:20, watched: false

3) from: 2:20, to: 3:20, watched: true

calculation of each object requires knowledge about the previous one

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your input string? (and desired output?)

Comment: @RobAu, I just edited my answer

Comment: the duplicated questions' answer should contain enough information :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not about successive pairs, but about collecting cumulative prefix. In functional programming such operation is usually called `scanLeft` and it's present in many functional languages like [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@scanLeft[B,That]%28z:B%29%28op:%28B,A%29=%3EB%29%28implicitbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Repr,B,That]%29:That). Unfortunately it's absent in current implementation of Java 8 Stream API, so we can only emulate it with `forEachOrdered`. Let's create a model object:

```
static class WatchPeriod {
    static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
    final LocalTime start;
    final Duration duration;
    final boolean watched;

    WatchPeriod(LocalTime start, Duration duration, boolean watched) {
        this.start = start;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.watched = watched;
    }

    // Takes string like "A60" and creates WatchPeriod starting from 00:00
    static WatchPeriod forString(String watchPeriod) {
        return new WatchPeriod(LocalTime.of(0, 0),
                   Duration.ofMinutes(Integer.parseInt(watchPeriod.substring(1))),
                   watchPeriod.startsWith("A"));
    }

    // Returns new WatchPeriod which start time is adjusted to start
    // right after the supplied previous period
    WatchPeriod after(WatchPeriod previous) {
        return new WatchPeriod(previous.start.plus(previous.duration), duration, watched);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "from: "+start.format(FORMATTER)+", to: "+
            start.plus(duration).format(FORMATTER)+", watched: "+watched;
    }
}
```

Now we can split the input string like `"A60B80A60"` to the tokens `"A60", "B80", "A60"`, map these tokens to `WatchPeriod` objects, then store them into the resulting list:

```
String input = "A60B80A60";
List<WatchPeriod> result = new ArrayList<>();
Pattern.compile("(?=[AB])").splitAsStream(input)
    .map(WatchPeriod::forString)
    .forEachOrdered(wp -> result.add(result.isEmpty() ? wp : 
                          wp.after(result.get(result.size()-1))));
result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

The output is:

```
from: 00:00, to: 01:00, watched: true
from: 01:00, to: 02:20, watched: false
from: 02:20, to: 03:20, watched: true
```

If you don't mind using third-party library, my free [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) enhances Stream API adding missing [`scanLeft`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#scanLeft-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) operation among other features:

```
String input = "A60B80A60";
List<WatchPeriod> result = StreamEx.split(input, "(?=[AB])")
        .map(WatchPeriod::forString).scanLeft((prev, next) -> next.after(prev));
result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

The result is the same.